# Get array data via position in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Following is my JSON format,

```
{
"records": [
{
"ID": "4",
"TYPE": "landscape",
"FIMAGE": "viewveni.jpg",
"COUNT": "4444"
}
],
"pagination": {
"count": 1,
"page": 1,
"limit": 10,
"totalpages": 1
}
}
```

I am trying really hard to fetch the `Second element` of `First element`, i.e. `records.TYPE`, but i can not use the index name `TYPE`.

I know `records[0][1]` won't work and i am really out of options now.

Edit:

I know I can fetch data as records[0].TYPE but I can't use TYPE as plain text, how ever if it's a variable then it's ok, ie. Something like `records[0].cat` where `cat = 'TYPE'`

Comment: You can try `let [key, val] = Object.entries(records[0])[1]` but results may be inconsistent (see Nikhil's answer below)

Comment: Is it possible to get the value inline? I know there are hundreds of ways to do this, but I want short inline solution, kindly check the updated questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `records[0].TYPE` or `records[0]["TYPE"]`.

Refer [MDN documentation on Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for more info.

> I am trying really hard to fetch the Second element of First element

`TYPE` is not the second element of records array element. Object properties are not ordered.

```js
var data = { "records": [{ "ID": "4", "TYPE": "landscape", "FIMAGE": "viewveni.jpg", "COUNT": "4444" }], "pagination": { "count": 1, "page": 1, "limit": 10, "totalpages": 1 } };

var result = data.records[0].TYPE;

console.log(result);
```

`Object.values(data.records[0])[1]` will give inconsistent results because object properties are not ordered.

```js
var data = { "records": [{ "ID": "4", "TYPE": "landscape", "FIMAGE": "viewveni.jpg", "COUNT": "4444" }], "pagination": { "count": 1, "page": 1, "limit": 10, "totalpages": 1 } };

console.log(Object.values(data.records[0])[1]);
```

If `TYPE` value will be stored in a variable, then you can use bracket notation to access the value.

```js
var data = { "records": [{ "ID": "4", "TYPE": "landscape", "FIMAGE": "viewveni.jpg", "COUNT": "4444" }], "pagination": { "count": 1, "page": 1, "limit": 10, "totalpages": 1 } };

let prop = "TYPE";

console.log(data.records[0][prop]);
```

Comment: ` i can not use the index name TYPE`, sorry!

Comment: `TYPE` is not an index, it is a property of the object. There is no second element in objects because object properties are not ordered. You can use `Object.values(data.records[0])[1]` but you'll get different output each time, so it shouldn't be used.

Comment: Are JavaScript variable indexes are case sensitive?

Comment: @Mercurial - Yes, they are case sensitive.